# Can't get the JSONP working with WCF Data Services

Tags: .net, wcf, jsonp, wcf-data-services

It seems from all that I read and watched, exposing JSON from a WCF Data Service should be as easy as adding the `JSONPSupportBehavior` attribute to the service class.

The problem is that VS2010 doesn't recognize the `JSONPSupportBehavior` attribute.

Is there a reference I am missing?  It seems like from all the articles, it was supported out of the box.

Comment: I don't think that it's included by default yet. See this [link](http://code.google.com/p/dotnet-visualization-datasource/source/browse/trunk/Web+Services/WCFDataService/JSONPSupportBehavior.cs?spec=svn84&r=84) for some example code.

Comment: Download the code [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=DataServicesJSONP&DownloadId=11208). This one actually works!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

WCF Data Services supports JSON out of the box, no need to add attributes or anything.

In order to receive a response in JSON format clients use standard HTTP content type negotiation.

Specifically, they need to include `application/json` in the `accept` header of the request.

There are examples in this section of the [OData protocol documentation](http://www.odata.org/developers/protocols/operations#RetrievingfeedsEntriesandservicedocument).

These examples show the raw HTTP requests.  Different client HTTP APIs have different mechanisms to specify request headers.

The `JSONPSupportBehavior` attribute is an example of an extension that allows clients to use a URL query string option (i.e. `$format=json`) in addition to content-type negotiation, and also adds support for "JSONP" (i.e. `$callback=[function-name]`).

These are useful in situations where you don't control the headers, such as when doing cross-domain access through script tags.

If you want to use the `JSONPSupportBehavior` you can obtain it here:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/DataServicesJSONP

Comment: YEs, I had been to the link you supplied but missed the download link which had the class file in it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Newer versions of WCF Data Services support JSON by default and you must have

```
Accept: application/json;odata=verbose
```

in the request header.

```
Accept: application/json
```

is no longer sufficient. More info [here](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2013/01/28/why-my-wcf-data-service-isn-t-returning-json-format.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

WCF not only suppors JSON out-of-the-box, but it also supports JSONP out-of-the-box if you use WCF WebApi (preview 6).  Get in VS 2010 with NuGet.  Once you have it installed, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803264/c-sharp-wcf-web-api-jsonp/8990334#8990334) for more information.