# jquery wcf data service returns atom+xml instead of json

Tags: jquery, wcf, json

Locally everything works fine but when I deploy the wcf data service to server the response is atom+xml.  Am I missing something?

jquery

```
      $(function () {
                $.ajax({                    
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                    url: "http://subdomain.domain.com/wcfdataservice.svc/surveys/",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    success: function (data, textStatus) {

                    },
                    error: function (data, textStatus) {

                    }
                });      

        });
```

wcf web.config

```
    <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0" />

<authentication mode="None"/>

</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
<system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <standardEndpoints>
        <webHttpEndpoint>
            <standardEndpoint name="" helpEnabled="true" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" crossDomainScriptAccessEnabled="true" />
        </webHttpEndpoint>
    </standardEndpoints>

</system.serviceModel>
```

fiddler

```
        HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 13483
Content-Type: application/atom+xml;charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
DataServiceVersion: 2.0;
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 25 Mar 2011 17:46:37 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<feed xml:base="http://subdomain.domain.com/wcfdataservice.svc/" xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think Pablo Castro's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983078/cant-get-the-jsonp-workin-with-wcf-data-services) to this question is the solution you're looking for.

Basically, you need to specify an "accept" header of "application/json" in your request, and also optionally use the `[JSONPSupportBehavior]` attribute on your service.  I think, since you're controlling both ends, the accept header is all you need.

**EDIT**:  If you examine, with Fiddler, your request and you don't see the 'Accept' header being set or not being set correctly, you may be able to use this technique in this article:

http://snipplr.com/view/9869/set-jquery-ajax-header/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier to do now using WCF WebApi (preview 6).  You'll have to install the WCF WebApi using NuGet, but it's worth it.  Once you have it installed, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803264/c-sharp-wcf-web-api-jsonp/8990334#8990334) for more information.